# jQuery get updated value of element's html()

Tags: jquery, tinymce

In the code below, I'm binding the click event for the span so that it fires off the checkTOC function.

In that function, I'm storing a count of matched elements in the count variable. This works great, as long as the content is not changed after the page load. However, the value of count does not appear to be affected by post page load changes to the #content div.

How can I alter the code so that the count reflects the updated value of #content html?

```
if(typeof jQuery!="undefined")
    {
        jQuery(document).ready(function($)
        {

        var checkTOC = function()
        {
            //find the count of <!--nextpage--> elements
            var count = jQuery('#content').html().split("&lt;!--nextpage--&gt;").length - 1;

            alert(count);//ALWAYS RETURNS THE INITIAL COUNT, REGARDLESS IF ACTUAL COUNT IS CHANGED AFTER PAGE LOAD VIA HTML EDITING

            var pageurl = jQuery("#view-post-btn a").attr("href");
            var htmlStrTOCpre = jQuery("#cb2_customTOC").text();
            var htmlStrTOC  = '<summary>Table of Contents</summary>\n';
            htmlStrTOC += '<ol>\n';
            htmlStrTOC += '    <li><a href="'+pageurl+'">Introduction</a></li>\n';

            for (var i = 2; i < count+2; i++) {
                htmlStrTOC += '    <li><a href="'+pageurl+i+'/">Page'+i+'</a></li>\n';
            }

            htmlStrTOC += '</ol>';

            jQuery("#cb2_customTOC").val(htmlStrTOC);
        }

        jQuery("#cb-toc-click").bind("click", checkTOC);

        });
    }
```

HTML code

```
<span id="cb-toc-click">Paste Table of Contents</span>
```

Comment: Why are you splitting html? There are many efficient ways for counting elements.

Comment: Good point I'm sure but I'm counting specific comment tags that are not really dom level "elements"...

Comment: Is counting comments the only way for counting them? Are you sure that updated contents have comments?

Comment: Yes, I can remove comments from the html and click the span. The count always reflects the count at load time, not the correct count after post-load edits to the content.

Comment: Okay, if you have control over html, you can add classes to the elements and use `find` method, `$('#content').find('.nextPages').length`

Comment: Comments can't have classes. I'm counting the number of <!--nextpage--> comments in the html of the #content div

Comment: Yes, comments can't have classes, I meant to say add classes to the _elements_! like Div elements. What is the type of `#cb2_customTOC` element? `div`?

Comment: The issue is not the elements, its the fact that html() is apparently being treated as a static variable. I need it to be a dynamic variable based on the live value of the #content div at the time the paste event is fired.

Comment: Have you verified that `.html()` is not returning the updated HTML content? Can you put an example on JSFiddle?

Comment: alert(count) always returns the same value. Same with alert(jQuery('#content').html())

Answer (score 0):

You could traverse the DOM with vanilla JS or, rather, `#content`'s children nodes recursively and check for their [`element.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/DOM/element.nodeType) value. If it is equivalent to `Node.COMMENT_NODE` (or just `8` if you prefer magic numbers ;) than it means you're dealing with a comment. With that in mind, you can build any kind of logic:

```
var commentCount = 0;
//anonymous function to be called recursively
(function(D) {
    //if this is a comment, increment the counter
    8===D.nodeType&&commentCount++;
    //call the same function recursively for every child node
    D=D.firstChild;
    while (D) {
        arguments.callee(D);
        D=D.nextSibling;
    }
})(document.getElementById('content'));//start with #content
```

[Fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/EuYJK/2/)

That being said, I agree with the comments that there are better ways of dealing with the task if you have control over markup.

Answer (score 0):

> alert(count) always returns the same value. Same with
>   alert(jQuery('#content').html()) –

Problem here is that the editor content is not in `jQuery('#content')` due to the fact that tinymce creates a contenteditable iframe on editor initialization which is then used to edit content. This contetn gets written back on several tinymce events.

To get the recent editor content you should use the following

```
$(tinymce.get('your_editor_id').getBody()).html();
```

Comment: Actually alert(jQuery('#content').html()) does in fact contain the editor's content. However, its stale content, not fresh.

Comment: that's what i am talking about: it is old content - use the code i provided to get the actual one